# PyLint, XLSXWriter Error: No value for argument 'last_col' in method call merge_range()

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Python pyLint complains xlsxwriter's `worksheet.merge_range()` method has error:

> "No value for argument 'last_col' in method call"
>   and "No value for argument 'data' in method call"

When [xlsxwriter's documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html) gives example `worksheet.merge_range('B3:D4', 'Merged Cells', merge_format)`. With method details:

> merge_range(first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col, data[, cell_format])

Here is my code that is causing this problem.

```
worksheet.merge_range('C1:E1', 'DATE', format4)
```

**Is there any workaround or fix for this problem?** I am using xlsxwiter version:
`>>> print(xlsxwriter.__version__)
0.9.6`

and python version:
`Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 20:20:57) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The method documentation says the method is expecting 5 or 6 parameters. PyLint says it is expecting a value for `data` which is the 5th parameter. The example call you are following passes only three parameters. It looks like the example is wrong.

Comment: @BoarGules So I should just insert a few Nonetypes into the data and last_col parameters?

Comment: Well that will certainly stop PyLint from complaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only optional parameter defined in this method is `cell_format`, so, PyLint is telling you that you have to define all the other ones.

To fix this, you can set `None` to the other ones.

Comment: Ok thank you. Weird how the documentation doesn't have any information about this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a false positive from Pylint.

The `merge_range()` method has a decorator to allow either `A1` or `(row, col)` notation. From the code:

```
@convert_range_args
def merge_range(self, first_row, first_col, last_row, last_col,
                data, cell_format=None):
```

You are using the decorator version:

```
worksheet.merge_range('C1:E1', 'DATE', format4)
```

Which equates to:

```
worksheet.merge_range(0, 2, 0, 4, 'DATE', format4)
```

Pylint is incorrectly applying the rule for the second method signature to the decorator invocation. Although in fairness there probably isn't a way for it to determine that it is valid.

So either use the `(row, col)` syntax or just ignore the warning. See also [Working with Cell Notation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html) from the XlsxWriter docs.